# Client-side verification of HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am using Django and Python to write a website. In one webpage, I have an HTML form, with a set of radio buttons and a submit button. On form submission, I want to verify that a radio button has in fact been selected, rather than all radio buttons left black as is default.

One way of doing this is to do the check on the server side. I would check the POST data, and see whether the relevant field, indicating the selected radio button, has been set. If this field has not been set, then I would return to the same webpage, and display the message "Please try again". This works fine for me.

However, this seems a bit of an overkill. Is there any way I can do this same check in Javascript (jQuery), and return this same webpage and error message?

Comment: You should look at HTML5 contraint validation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

Comment: Might a bit overpowered for one form but this might also interssting http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML & JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateRadioButtons(){ 
var radio = $('input:radio[name="IdName"]:checked');
if(radio.length == 0)//no buttons selected
   {
       $('ValidationError').text("you haven't selected any buttons!");
       return;
   }
$('ValidationError').text(radio.val()+' is selected');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div>
<span>
<input type="radio" name="IdName" value="Id1"/>
Id1
<input type="radio" name="IdName" value="Id2"/>
Id2
</span>
<div id="ValidationError" name="ValidationError">
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateRadioButtons();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Django-parsley](https://github.com/agiliq/django-parsley) to attach client side validation to your existing forms.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery the validation code will be something like this.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
        if($('input[type=radio]:checked').val() == ''){
           alert('please select radio buttion');
           return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check one radio-button by default by adding `checked` in the input field of the button you want to check by default. That ensures at least one input box will always be selected.

```
<input type="radio" checked />
```